# Editing custom views in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I currently have SP list that contains the following columns.

Item, Category & Description

Within column Category there is string value "not progressed". Id like to display everything except this value in a view. However there seems to be no option to ignore this string when i try and edit my view.

Can anyone help ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a filter.

In SP 2007:

1. click modify view
2. in the filter section select "Show items only when the following is true:"
3. select Category from the first drop down in the filter section
4. select "is not equal to" in the second drop down in the filter section
5. type "not progressed" in the text box in the filter section